# How to prove a function derived from subspace of $L_{\infty}$ where the sequence has limit is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

So I have a subspace $M$, which is defined by:
$M=\{a=\{a_k\}K\in L^{∞}$|lim_{k→∞} exists}.
Now define a function $u:M→C$ that $u(a)=lim(a_k)$. How to prove it is bounded? I saw an answer that “suppose $a\in M$ with $||a||=1$”. How could I do that? I think the definition of bounded function is that for all the value of the function we can find a number $a$ such that $a$ is bigger than all the value of the function but not on the opposite.